# Byte to bits in a BMP getting RGB

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, bitmap, rgb

I wrote the code below in order to manipulate the color of an image. I want to somehow rip apart each pixel of the image. So for each pixel, i want access to the 5 bits of red, 6 bits of green and 5 bits of blue (as per 16 bit images). How would i change my code to do this? I guess i would have to somehow convert those byte values which i'm setting to bits?

Any help would be great.

```
        private Bitmap InvertBitmap(Bitmap bmp)
        {

            unsafe
            {
                //create an empty bitmap the same size as original
                Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(bmp.Width, bmp.Height);

            //lock the original bitmap in memory
            System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData originalData = bmp.LockBits(
               new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
               System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

            //lock the new bitmap in memory
            System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData newData = newBitmap.LockBits(
               new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
               System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

            //set the number of bytes per pixel
            int pixelSize = 3;

            for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
            {
                //get the data from the original image
                byte* originalImageRow = (byte*)originalData.Scan0 + (y * originalData.Stride);

                //get the data from the new image
                byte* newImageRow = (byte*)newData.Scan0 + (y * newData.Stride);

                for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
                {

                    //set the new image's pixel to the inverted version

                    newImageRow[x * pixelSize] = (byte)(255 - originalImageRow[x * pixelSize + 0]); //B
                    newImageRow[x * pixelSize + 1] = (byte)(255 - originalImageRow[x * pixelSize + 1]); //G
                    newImageRow[x * pixelSize + 2] = (byte)(255 - originalImageRow[x * pixelSize + 2]); //R
                }
            }

            //unlock the bitmaps
            newBitmap.UnlockBits(newData);
            bmp.UnlockBits(originalData);

            return newBitmap;
        }
}
```

Comment: 565 is a 16-bpp encoding.  A 24-bpp image has 8 bits for R, G and B, nothing special is needed.

Comment: woops, your right, i wanted to take a 24 bit and manipulate it so that it's a 24 bit image with the color of a 16 bit, sorry, will fix that

Comment: Not sure that makes sense.  I guess you want to and the R and B with 0xf8 and the G with 0xfc to set the low bits to zero.  Use the & operator.  It will be hard to see the difference, especially on an LCD monitor.  The quickest way is just Graphics.DrawImage() the image into a 16bpp bitmap.

Comment: I'm not sure we're on the same page. Say i have a 24 bit image. I want to access the 8 bits for R (for instance) i want to change the least significant bits of the 8 bits to a different value. I want to change only 2 bits though so that it appears as a 16 bit.. i'll be storing other things in the 2 bits i'm manipulating.. does that make sense? I wasn't very clear in my Q.. sorry about that

Comment: As I explained, use & to set the low bits to 0, use | to put whatever data you want to put in the pixel.  Usually you only use 1 bit per pixel, in B since it is the least noticeable.  Google "steganography" for hits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a 16-bit integer x, you can extract ranges of bits within it by first masking those bits with a binary AND, then shifting the result.  Like so:

```
int x = 33808;  // 1000010000010000, for testing

int r = (x & 63488) >> 11;    // 63488 = 1111100000000000
int g = (x & 2016) >> 5;      //  2016 = 0000011111100000
int b = (x & 31);             //    31 = 0000000000011111

// r = 10000
// g = 100000
// b = 10000
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Hmm, so you mean store all the R G and B values in a 16bit int? and then from there pretty much parsing the int to get the bits?

Comment: i want to be able to change say 2 bits within the R value to something different in each pixel of the image..

Answer (score 1):

RGB24 is 1 byte per color channel so you don't need to do any bit twiddling to extract them from the data you already have.  "getting the bits" doesn't really make sense as you can set their values already e.g.

```
newImageRow[x * pixelSize] = (byte)(originalImageRow[x * pixelSize + 0] | 0x80); //B
```

will set the new image blue channel to the original image blue channel but will set the high order bit to 1.

```
newImageRow[x * pixelSize] = (byte)(originalImageRow[x * pixelSize + 0] ^ 0xFF); //B
```

will invert the channel.

So you really just need to use bitwise operators (| & >> << ^)on the data you already have.